# PDFjs not working in safari, blank page. How to solve issue?

Tags: reactjs, safari, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I'm using pdfjs-dist "^2.16.105" to import pdf files into fabric as fabric.Images in my React Application. According to the http://fabricjs.com/import-pdf example, this all works in Chrome, Firefox, but does not work in Safari. I'm testing in Safari version 14.1.2. Here's the error in the console when loading react app.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected private name #ensureObj. Cannot parse class method with private 
name.
```

I have read that safari versions before 14.5 does not support private classes. How can this problem be solved?
In Safari React application doesn't start, I only see a blank screen.

This is my code

```
import * as PDFJS from "pdfjs-dist";
import * as pdfjsWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry";

PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;

...
 PDFJS.getDocument({
        data: pdfData,
      }).promise.then((a) => {
        a.getPage(1).then((page) => {
          let viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: window.devicePixelRatio });
          const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
          canvas.height = viewport.height;
          canvas.width = viewport.width;

          const render_context = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport,
          };
          const renderTask = page.render(render_context);
          renderTask.promise.then(() => {
            const canvasImage = new fabric.Image(canvas, {});
            renderCanvasImg(canvasImage);
          });
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to downgrade pdf-dist library to `v2.4.456` since the version `v2.13.216` introduced `#ensureObj` - private fields ES2022 feature (see [build/pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist/compare/v2.12.313...v2.13.216)).

```json
package.json: 
{
  dependencies: {
    "pdfjs-dist": "v2.4.456",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

[image]

Second possibility would be to use some transpiler (etc. Babel) to downgrade the ES version.